# I want a regex for this?

Tags: regex

I am not an expert at regex. 
I want a regex for following requirements

1. There has to be 1 occurrence of string "[number]" (brackets included) (multiple occurrences allowed)
2. There can be characters before or after [number] (provided those characters comply to : ([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]) ie: things allowed in an email.
3. 0 or more occurrences of string "[country]" are allowed anywhere

Currently I have:

```
^([[number])?([[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)?([[number])?([[country])?([[number])?([[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)?([[number])?[[number]([[number])?([[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)?([[number])?([[country])?([[number])?([[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)?([[number])?([[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)?
```

I do not think this is complete.

Comment: Maybe you should try [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Sample inputs will be difficult because there are millions of possibilities.

Comment: It will be helpful to provide a few things which _should_ match, as well as a few which _should not_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, this is horrbile... I think, this one will do:

```
((\[country\]|[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.])*\[number\])+(\[country\]|[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.])*
```

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to set most of those groups to noncapturing, but the regex looks fine to me. It would be worthwhile to explain your regex, or provide a regex101/debuggex/regexr/etc link to aid in understanding for both the OP as well as future viewers.